# Angular 5 Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular-router

I get the blow error in angular for HomeComponent

```
 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15706)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15541)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:15026)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14880)
at eval (compiler.js:34420)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at eval (compiler.js:34419)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34416)
```

HomeComponent.ts

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {endpointLocation} from '../endpoint';
import {SimpleGlobal} from 'ng2-simple-global';
import {Headers, Http, Request, RequestMethod, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {AuthHttp} from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  email: string;
  endpoints: string;
  msg: string;

  title: string;
  mailVerificationCode: string;

  message: string;

  answer: string;
  cnfPassword: string;
  password: string;
  showResetPassword: boolean;

  showLoginButton = 'none';

  // title: string;
  alertStatus: string;

  loginStatus: boolean;
  username: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private route: Router, private sg: SimpleGlobal, private _http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp) {
    this.endpoints = endpointLocation.EXCHANGE;
    if (localStorage.getItem('kryptoexlogin') === 'true') {
      this.loginStatus = true;
    } else {
      this.loginStatus = false;
    }
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('kryptoexusername');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let server = location.href;

    if (server.indexOf('verification_token') !== -1) {
      let param = server.split('?');
      if (param[1].indexOf('verification_token') !== -1) {
        let token = param[1].split('=');
        this.mailVerificationCode = token[1];
        if (this.mailVerificationCode.length !== 0) {
          this.title = 'Email Verification';
          this.verifyEmail();
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
        }
      }
    } else if (server.indexOf('ipauth_token') !== -1) {
      let param = server.split('?');
      if (param[1].indexOf('ipauth_token') !== -1) {
        let token = param[1].split('=');
        this.mailVerificationCode = token[1];
        if (this.mailVerificationCode.length !== 0) {
          this.title = 'Ip Authentication';
          this.verifyIpAuth();
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
        }
      }
    } else if (server.indexOf('reset_token') !== -1) {
      let param = server.split('?');
      if (param[1].indexOf('reset_token') !== -1) {
        let token = param[1].split('=');
        this.mailVerificationCode = token[1];
        if (this.mailVerificationCode.length !== 0) {
          this.title = 'Reset Password';
          this.showResetPassword = true;
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
        }
      }
    } else if (server.indexOf('disable_2fa') !== -1) {
      let param = server.split('?');
      if (param[1].indexOf('disable_2fa') !== -1) {
        let token = param[1].split('=');
        this.mailVerificationCode = token[1];
        if (this.mailVerificationCode.length !== 0) {
          this.title = 'Disabling Two Factor Authentication';
          this.dsiable2FA();
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setResetPassword() {
    if ((this.answer !== null || this.answer !== '' || this.answer !== undefined) && (this.password === null || this.password === '' || this.password === undefined)) {
      this.password = this.answer;
      this.answer = '';
    } else if (this.password !== null || this.password !== '' || this.password !== undefined) {
      if (this.answer !== null || this.answer !== '' || this.answer !== undefined) {
        this.cnfPassword = this.answer;
        this.answer = '';
        this.resetPassword();
      }
    }
  }


  verifyEmail() {
    this.msg = 'Your account is being validated, please wait....';

    let url = this.endpoints.concat('user/verify/email/' + this.mailVerificationCode + '/');

    this.httGet(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.msg = data.msg;
        if (data.status) {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-success';
          this.showLoginButton = 'block';
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-danger';
        }
      }, erorr => {
        this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
        this.msg = 'Problem in verifying your mail, please try again later...';
      }, () => console.log('finished verifying mail')
    );
  }

  resetPassword() {

    if (this.password === this.cnfPassword) {
      this.msg = 'Resetting your password...';

      let param = {
        'password': this.password
      };

      let url = this.endpoints.concat('user/reset_password_link/validate/' + this.mailVerificationCode + '/');

      this.httPost(param, url).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.msg = data.msg;
          if (data.status) {
            this.alertStatus = 'alert-success';
            this.showLoginButton = 'block';
          } else {
            this.alertStatus = 'alert-danger';
          }
        }, erorr => {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-warning';
          this.msg = 'Problem in verifying your mail, please try again later...';
        }, () => console.log('finished verifying mail')
      );
    } else {
      this.msg = 'Passwords does not match';
    }
  }

  verifyIpAuth() {
    this.msg = 'Your IP is being authenticated, please wait....';

    let url = this.endpoints.concat('user/validate_ipauth_access/' + this.mailVerificationCode);

    this.httGet(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.msg = data.msg;
        if (data.status) {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-success';
          this.showLoginButton = 'block';
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-danger';
        }
      }, erorr => {
        this.msg = 'Problem in authenticating IP access, please try again later...';
      }, () => console.log('finished authenticating IP access')
    );
  }

  dsiable2FA() {
    this.msg = '2FA is being disabled, please wait...';

    let url = this.endpoints.concat('verification/disable/token/2fa/' + this.mailVerificationCode);

    this.httGet(url).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.msg = data.msg;
        if (data.status) {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-success';
          this.showLoginButton = 'block';
        } else {
          this.alertStatus = 'alert-danger';
        }
      }, erorr => {
        this.msg = 'Problem in disabling 2fa';
      }, () => console.log('finished disabling 2fa')
    );
  }

  reset() {
    this.msg = null;
    this.password = null;

  }

  resetForm() {

    this.reset();
  }

  /*http service methods*/
  httGet(url: string) {
    return this._http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  httDelete(url: string) {
    return this._http.delete(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  httPost(param: any, url: string) {
    var headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod.Post,
      url: url,
      headers: headers,
      body: param
    });

    return this._http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  httpGetAuth(url: string) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('kryptoextoken'));
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this._http.get(url, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  httpPostAuth(param: any, url: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('kryptoextoken'));

    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      method: RequestMethod.Post,
      url: url,
      headers: headers,
      body: param
    });

    return this._http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

above is my HomeComponent.ts file, please let me know where I am missing.
I just use the Http, Router. The same file works in Angular 6, but it does not work in angular 5, I need to work out this in angular 5 because I use Tradviewchart which works only on Angular 5

Comment: Home component ts file?

Comment: please check now and let me know where I am missing

Comment: Which version of angular2-jwt are you using? https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt says: @auth0/angular-jwt v2 is to be used with Angular v6+ and RxJS v6+. For Angular v4.3 to v5+, use @auth0/angular-jwt v1

Comment: does the error message actually have those question marks?

Comment: I could find the same error in the browser console, but it does not throw any error while running the app